# Material-UI Autocomplete & TextField triggers google autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to implement the Autocomplete component into my project but am getting the autofill/autocomplete from the browser after some time. Do you know how I can set it to off ?

```
                        <Autocomplete

                            id="combo-box-demo"
                            options={battleRepos}
                            getOptionLabel={option => option.full_name}
                            style={{ width: 500 }}
                            renderInput={params => (
                                <TextField {...params} 
                                    label="Combo box"  
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    onBlur={event => console.log(event.target.value)}

                                    fullWidth  />
                            )}
                        />
```

[image: Image with the problem]

Comment: try adding attribute `autocomplete="off"`to `TextField`

Comment: that doesn't work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With the release of @material-ui/core 4.7.0 and @material-ui/lab 4.0.0-alpha.33, this is now fixed and no longer requires the workaround shown below.

---

This has been fixed in a recent [pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/18376), but is not yet released (will be in the next release).

If you want to work around this prior to it being released (which will likely be within a few days), you can set `inputProps.autoComplete = "off"` like in the following:

```
<Autocomplete
    id="combo-box-demo"
    options={battleRepos}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.full_name}
    style={{ width: 500 }}
    renderInput={params => {
        const inputProps = params.inputProps;
        inputProps.autoComplete = "off";
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            inputProps={inputProps}
            label="Combo box"  
            variant="outlined"
            onBlur={event => console.log(event.target.value)}
            fullWidth
          />
        );
      }
    }
/>
```

Comment: When I try this I am getting an error related inputProps.autoComplete. The error is: Property 'autoComplete' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)

Comment: @JoshuaScott I don't personally use TypeScript, so I'm not going to help with TypeScript issues, but the next release will be out shortly and then this will take care of itself by updating to the latest lab version without needing this workaround.

Comment: @JoshuaScott, cast it to any

Comment: @JoshuaScott See my update -- the bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Even with the latest:

```
 "@material-ui/core" 
 "@material-ui/lab"
```

which contains the autoComplete property set to `'off'`, I wasn't able to get the autofill box go away.

Also tried setting the attribute on the form tag `<form autoComplete="off">...</form>`

To no avail.

The thing which resolved the issue was setting the autoComplete field to 'new-password'

```
<Autocomplete
    id='id'
    options={data}
    onChange={(e, val) => input.onChange(val)}
    renderInput={(params) => {
        params.inputProps.autoComplete = 'new-password';
        return <TextField {...params}
            label={label} placeholder="Type to Search" />
    }} 
/>
```

Comment: Also can be added just as `inputProps={{ ...params.inputProps, autoComplete: 'new-password' }}` on <TextField> (to avoid TypeScript errors mentioned above)